# IBM Watson Visual Recognition (NodeJS) - Error code 403 : Forbidden: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: node.js, express, ibm-watson, http-status-code-403, visual-recognition

I am currently using Watson Visual Recognition API in the environment below but getting 403 invalid credential error.
For your information I am running this on Ubuntu Server 16.04.6 LTS in VMware Workstation 15.5.1.
The Node js code is from IBM Cloud webpage in below URL and I input the api key in my credentials.
I already installed npm by using following command and  following [the guide](https://cloud.ibm.com/services/watson-vision-combined/crn%3Av1%3Abluemix%3Apublic%3Awatson-vision-combined%3Akr-seo%3Aa%2F3c39eb8a5d083bd38ae87b5e3f39a164%3A21afa927-7f6d-48ef-acb0-2fc7adbb9195%3A%3A?paneId=gettingStarted).

```
npm install --save watson-developer-cloud
```

```
var VisualRecognitionV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition/v3');
var fs = require('fs');

var visualRecognition = new VisualRecognitionV3({
  version: '2018-03-19',
  iam_apikey: 'Hy-N8Lxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  // used api key in my credentials
});

var url= 'https://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/doc-tutorial-downloads/visual-recognition/640px-IBM_VGA_90X8941_on_PS55.jpg';

var params = {
  url: url,
};

visualRecognition.classify(params, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))
  }
});
```

When I execute the command `node {filename}.js` in the command line, I get the error message like below. For this error, the code is 403 and when I input the wrong API key, error code 400 appear so I don't think the error is on wrong api key.

```
Forbidden: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
    at formatError (/home/byungmin/visual_recognition/node_modules/ibm-cloud-sdk                                       -core/lib/requestwrapper.js:111:17)
    at /home/byungmin/visual_recognition/node_modules/ibm-cloud-sdk-core/lib/req                                       uestwrapper.js:259:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5) {
  name: 'Forbidden',
  code: 403,
  message: 'Access is denied due to invalid credentials.',
  body: '{"code":403,"error":"Forbidden"}',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '34',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;',
    'x-edgeconnect-midmile-rtt': '224',
    'x-edgeconnect-origin-mex-latency': '49',
    date: 'Fri, 21 Feb 2020 12:56:10 GMT',
    connection: 'close'
  }
}
```

Appreciated if you can help me find the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for lite account:

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');
    var VisualRecognitionV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition/v3');


        var visualRecognition = new VisualRecognitionV3({
          authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({
            apikey: 'Hy-N8Lxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

          }),
          url: 'https://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/doc-tutorial-downloads/visual-recognition/640px-IBM_VGA_90X8941_on_PS55.jpg',
        });

var params = {
  url: url,
};

visualRecognition.classify(params, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))
  }
});
```

Comment: It works! not adding "const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');" code was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a “Lite” (free) plan?  With that plan you would be limited to 1000 images for training and tagging combined in a month. Most likely you have reached that limit.  Upgrading your account to Standard will preserve any trained classifiers and allow as much usage as you want.

Comment: Actually it was not long that I started this. I don't think this is related to image number limits.

Answer (score 0):

If Lite plan overage isn't your issue, check that you specified the base URL at `url: url`, and that url matches the one shown in the credentials for the API key that you used. See the [API reference](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition/visual-recognition-v3?code=node#service-endpoint) for details.

Comment: not adding "const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');" code was the issue.